# WooCommerce как отцепить события от хука?

Tags: woocommerce

в WooCommerce где идет вывод товара есть такой хук

```
/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_before_main_content.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
 * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_website_data() - 30
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );?>
```

По описанию видно что он грузит woocommerce_output_content_wrapper и woocommerce_breadcrumb . Так вот вопрос, каким образом можно сделать что бы убрать woocommerce_breadcrumb , так как вывода в этом месте нельзя, и я вывожу в нужном месте через саму функцию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в functions.php вашей темы

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20 );
```